# getAs( ) - Migration Apache Spark 1.6.3 to Apache Spark 2.2.0

Tags: java, apache-spark, migration, apache-spark-2.0

I recently migrated from Apache Spark 1.6.3 to version 2.2.0 and I have some issues with some functions that have changed

in SPARK 1.6.3 i´m doing that way ,

THE CODE IS IN JAVA

```
    List<String[]> list_id_fk = dfHBaseTemp.toJavaRDD().map(l -> {
            String[] arrayListFK = {"", ""};
            arrayListFK[0] = l.getAs("ID_KEY");
            arrayListFK[1] = l.getAs("ID_TW");
            //System.out.println(arrayListFK[0] +" "+ arrayListFK[1]);
            return arrayListFK;
        }).collect();
```

THE `.getAs("ID_KEY")`; is not a valid method in Version 2.2.0 !!

Now in SPAKR 2.2.0 should I do ?

Thanks !

Comment: `getAs(string fieldname)` is a valid method on `Row` in Spark 2.2. Maybe `l` is not a `Row` anymore because the dataset is strongly typed?

Comment: what type of variable is "dfHBaseTemp"

Comment: Hi @AmitKumar dfHBaseTemp was Dataframe , now is Dataset !

Comment: Hi @RaphaelRoth the `l` in spark 1.6 was a Row , now i was expecting that it is Row too.